# A fluid adaptive unordered horizontal list

Tags: css, html-lists, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I'm wondering if there's a solution to this: (possibly not, but you never know!)

Assuming we have a ul list like this one:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/">What we do</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Human resources</a></li>
<li><a href="/">How we work</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Management</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Multimedia</a></li>
</ul>
```

and our CSS makes it display horizontally with the inline-block trick:

```
.nav li {display:inline-block;}
```

and we add some basic visuals

```
.nav li {border-right: 3px solid #ffb521;}
.nav a:link, .nav a:visited {color: #a51d21;font: bold 18px/18px Calibri,Tahoma,sans-serif;padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;display: block;background: #ffd074;}
.nav a:hover, .nav a:active {background:#a54d24;color:#ffd074;}
```

nothing special.

Here's also the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rjsaQ/

So here comes the question: How can I ensure that my horizontal list, will stretch and take all available space, but won't go to the next line. I guess I should remove the paddings, and play with max-width, but I tried it and it doesn't really work. Should I combine width and max-width?

Thanks in advance for your time and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, you should set list to `display: table` and list items `display: table-cell` but this solution is not cross browser

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rjsaQ/1/